# Navigated fragment shows behind the previous fragment in Navigation architecture component jetpack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

[image: Here the RestaurantListFragment is still visible after I navigate To RestaurantDetailFragment]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/restaurantListFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/scanQRFragment"
        android:name="com.example.dine.ui.view.home.scan_qr.ScanQRFragment"
        android:label="fragment_scan_q_r"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_scan_q_r" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/restaurantListFragment"
        android:name="com.example.dine.ui.view.home.restaurants.RestaurantListFragment"
        android:label="fragment_restaurant_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_restaurant_list" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_restaurantListFragment_to_restaruntDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/restaruntDetailFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/restaurantListFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myPlateFragment"
        android:name="com.example.dine.ui.view.home.my_plate.MyPlateFragment"
        android:label="fragment_my_plate"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my_plate" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/accountFragment"
        android:name="com.example.dine.ui.view.home.account.AccountFragment"
        android:label="fragment_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/restaruntDetailFragment"
        android:name="com.example.dine.ui.view.restaurant_detail.RestaruntDetailFragment"
        android:label="RestaruntDetailFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_restarunt_detail" />
</navigation>
```

Here is the navigation graph file I have used for this navigation fragments.

```
private fun onItemSelected() {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_restaurantListFragment_to_restaruntDetailFragment)
}
```

I called the `**onItemSelected()** method on a action, any help would be great. thanks

While Navigating from Restaurant list to RestaurantDetail fragment It comes like this. I have been suffering from this issue so long

Comment: How do you add your `NavHostFragment` to your layout? It sounds like you have two `NavHostFragment` instances in your layout.

Comment: I have the same issue with new fragment manager when call `navigation()` before `onStart`

Comment: how did you solve it ? @IR42

Comment: did you resolve it?

Comment: Yes! I have replaced the <fragment> tag to <FragmentContainerView> in activity xml file